# Make it more obvious you're answering a (very) old question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I just spent 20 minutes answering a year and a half old question that got bumped to the front page by a mostly meaningless edit (cant fixed to can't, a pair of backticks). The question was asked by a 1-rep user wth one question which hasn't visited Stack Overflow for over a year.

I didn't notice it was an old question when I answered it − I only saw afterwards. Perhaps this is a bit silly, but it's just a small box and more importantly, it was *on the front page*...

Now, there is nothing wrong with answering old questions as such, one of the great values of Stack Overflow is that it's a "repository of knowledge". But this was not one of those questions that greatly improved on this repository of knowledge − it was just someone being confused about some syntax.

In other words, I just wasted 20 minutes of my life. It's unlikely my answer will even be *seen* by the OP, and even more unlikely the OP will actually be helped by my answer since she has (hopefully) long since fixed the problem and moved on.

Can we have some way to make it a bit more obvious you're answering an old question?

Some possibilities might be:

- A little (unobtrusive) warning box when starting to type in the answer field similar to those you get when you ask a "bad" question (e.g. like entering "Best way to do foo?" as the question title).
- Don't show the for an old question, but a "Answer This Old Question"-button similar to the "Add Another Answer" when you already have an answer.

As a side-effect, this might also help with some of the "late answers from new users" queue. A good number of the people answering those questions seem to have the same confusion...

Comment: I'm guessing you'll hear the standard refrain of "we're not here to help the OP but everyone else", but I see you mention that it's not a great question anyway. I like the idea.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The question is okay in the sense that it states a clear goal, has a MCVE, and has a clear problem statement. It just isn't the sort of question that's likely to help other folk in the future (I avoided linking to it because of the meta effect :-/)

Comment: related: [Automatic visual indication of old questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98589/165773) at MSE

Comment: If the question is unlikely to help other visitors, maybe it should be closed as "no repro"?

Comment: I don't think "no repro" is an appropriate closing reason for something that has a MCVE and has a clear problem statement. It can certainly be reproduced. Hard to tell why that wouldn't help other visitors.

Comment: If the question is about greatly outdated software or procedures then an answer carries little weight, but a loss of time. The category of an old question should be a factor in this.

Comment: If the question was *edited* today, it was *seen* today as well - and to be dug up from the past, it must have been brought up as a search result. Just thinking out loud here...

Comment: @Mat'sMug it could have been brought up by Roomba's dice rolls, _then_ edited. Just playing devil's advocate here...

Comment: I just read the question and your answer. I think that the question is on-topic and will be helpful for future readers. Maybe edit the question to contain more search-likely words in prominent places so its more likely to be found by other people.

Comment: "this was not one of those questions that greatly improved on this repository of knowledge" then why answer it at all?

Comment: @Raedwald Because, as I explained in both in the question itself as in the comments below, if *would* most certainly have helped the author of the question.

Comment: Many of my biggest upvoted answers were from old questions! OP might not visit it again, but people will find your question through google just like you did, and you could help them out! :)

Comment: Wait, if it's "not a great question anyway" that's unlikely to help anyone later, why answer it then? Waste of 20 minutes either way as I see it...

Comment: LOL@ I just waited 20 minutes of my life.

Comment: Did you really waste 20 minutes of your life? Or did you spend 20 minutes of your life practicing your technical writing skills? It could be either. I strive to make it the latter. Most days, anyway.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a terrible idea and should not be implemented. Who cares when some asked the question as long people today are making use of the info provided.

Comment: @BryanOakley "Did you really waste 20 minutes of your life? Or did you spend 20 minutes of your life practicing your technical writing skills?" - Probably a bit of both. If all he wanted to do is practicing his technical writing skills he might find better (more interesting, better paid) opportunities elsewhere.

Answer (score 72):

This...raises questions.  Notably...

> It's unlikely my answer will even be seen by the OP, and even more unlikely the OP will actually be helped by my answer since she has (hopefully) long since fixed the problem and moved on.

This is a fair assessment (and is more than likely true), but...

> ...this was not one of those questions that greatly improved on this repository of knowledge − it was just someone being confused about some syntax.

Hence, the question:  if this question were asked today, would you have *still* invested 20 minutes on it?  What does the age of the question have to do with anything at that point if you readily admit that the question isn't one of those that would have improved on the repository of knowledge?

To that, I'm not sure that this sort of warning makes sense.  A person should be free to answer any question they wish so long as they're contributing a good and meaningful answer.  The OP may not come back to ever accept the answer, but if it's good enough and it gets some attention, then there's no reason to make that seem like a bad thing.

Comment: It would have helped the author a) fix the problem, and b) get a better understanding of what she's doing. How does that not "make any sense"? Not every question can help an entire class of people, but only the author − that doesn't mean there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: And to add to that, I have no intention of preventing anyone from doing anything − just make it more obvious *what* they are doing.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: But a pop-up warning sends the wrong message, suggesting that there is some reason they _shouldn't be doing that_, which is flat-out false.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker _"Not every question can help an entire class of people, but only the author − that doesn't mean there's anything wrong with it"_ No but it does mean it's off-topic.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet A popup warning is just one (possible) solution, and perhaps not the best one. Making it an explicit "Answer This Old Question" button (like it already is with "Answer Your Own Question" and "Add Another Answer") is probably a better solution ... Or perhaps something else is... And I don't see how these questions are somehow "off-topic".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: You have been informed several times on this page already. This is a Q&A repository, not a personal helpdesk. Q&As are for the benefit of all, _not_ ever just for the author of the question. A question that can only help its author is off-topic, because it is not broadly useful. That's the main crux of why your suggestion, though well-intentioned, seems like a misunderstanding of the model: answering an old question is _just fine_ because it's precisely as valuable as it was when it was posted. There is no need for a warning, or for a popup, or for concern of any kind.

Comment: ... besides, the post date is already quite prominent and easy to read. If you can't spot it you won't spot any other text displayed to you to show the same information.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet So which close reason do I choose then to close this question? Because I don't see a "not useful enough for future readers" close reason. Nor do I see anything about that in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You may personally not like these questions, and that's fine. Don't answer them, maybe downvote and move on. But don't expect everyone to abide by your personal preferences. Is it *possible* that my answer will help ...

Comment: ... someone in the future? Sure. Is it *likely*? No. Would my time have been better spent on answering a different question? Yes.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: These are not my "personal preferences". It's not that I "personally [do] not like these questions". It's a _categorical fact of the model_. This rule, and the way it steers site quality, is the entire purpose of Stack Overflow's existence! To answer your question, such problem posts can generally be closed as requiring a more _minimal_ example ([mcve]) because a problem with a MCVE is typically abstract enough to apply to a wide range of people. However, a close vote is not required - a downvote is appropriate, as if to mark the question as "not useful" (which it isn't).

Comment: (I agree that the Help Centre is not explicit about this. But if you search around meta it doesn't take much to see that I'm not lying. There used to be a "too localized" close reason _for precisely this case_, though it was removed due to abuse from frustrated regulars; I think the Help Centre prose hasn't been properly reworked to accommodate its removal as a pre-canned close reason.)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Not every problem or technology is wide-spread enough to "apply to a wide range of people". Like I said, it *could* perhaps help other folk in the future, it's just *exceedingly unlikely* given the obscureness of the involved language ([tag:csh]) and specific nature of the confusion. As I stated in the question, answering this question isn't somehow "wrong" *as such*, but the (potential) benefits are so low that I, personally, would not have chosen to spend time on this specific question had I known it was so old.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: That's okay - a question poster is not expected to be able to tell the future and count how many people literally found it useful. If it's well-written, and is _capable_ of having broader appeal than just to the author, that's sufficient. Again, an MCVE will tend to generate that automatically.

Comment: My point is that we have no reason to instigate a _policy_ of discouraging answering older questions rather than newer questions, so if it's your personal preference to avoid answering older questions then perhaps you should simply start paying more attention to your surroundings and read the post date before answering.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet It's not my intent to *discourage* anyone, but rather to *inform*. There's a subtle, yet important, difference. As for paying more attention, *shrug*, it's easy enough to mistake a question on the front page without any answers as a new question IMHO.

Comment: It matters a lot what a popup says, and what color it is.  Assuming we take that approach, it needs to be phrased and designed so as *not* to discourage people who already knew it was an old question.  I'm sure that's not too difficult.  Also, that doesn't solve the problem of wasting time puzzling out what the question is really asking, and what the OP is trying to do.  I sometimes get caught wasting reading time on a question bumped by tag edits or something, when it includes a code-dump that means the date isn't visible without scrolling.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker while that may not be your intention, it will be a side effect. People tend to be turned off if there's no hope for a reward for their action, and telling them that their answer will be likely to be ignored by the OP gives that impression.

Comment: @PeterCordes I normally end up voting to close those...

Answer (score 7):

Make a widget (or find someone to make it for you) which does this.

Your proposed solutions would definitely help someone who cared about the age of the question, but creates a number of problems.

- What is an old question?  Are questions asked over 30 days ago?  what about over 5 years?  What about questions which have not been touched (new answer or updates to existing content) for 30 days?
- How do you alert users that the question is old without implying that it is too old to be valid or too old to answer?
- What about the people who don't care how old it is?  How do they avoid the warnings (which would be rather common for a user like me).

When you throw in the prominence of when the question was asked and how many points the asker has (implying their site experience), the prominence of the page view, and how complex it would be to use that information to make a customized widget, the value of this feature is very low compared to its cost.

Creating your own widget will give you full control, while only impacting your user experience.  Then, if you find it is useful, you can share it with others.  In the event that it becomes super popular, create a new meta question asking for it to be incorporated into the site.

Comment: Has any user widget ever become "super popular"? Is this really the preferred way for changing how the site works? It sounds good but might be impractical.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't know if "_any user widget [has] ever become "super popular"_".  My point is that the request requires too much work for the expected number of people benefited, so it probably will not be picked up.  The widget solves the OP, but also provides a system for proving that the feature is (or is not) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Most questions here, if they get answered, get answered within 2 days (may depend on the popularity of the tag though).

If you answer a hitherto unanswered question more than, say, 7 days after creation it already might be that the questioner solved the problem differently or moved on (this is just my impression/experience).

If additionally the questioner hasn't been active for, say, more than half a year, chances are low he will ever notice your answer.

While it's useful to answer a good question of any age (search engine traffic), I have sympathies for those who take long age of the question and the absence of the questioner as reason not to answer.

The two critical values are already publicly displayed but a more visibly hint might be good.

I propose discreet and neutral visual hints for aged, unanswered questions and for aged, unanswered questions where the questioner hasn't been seen for quite some time.

Comment: Btw. I like answering also very old questions if the questions are good (no debugging help for example) and likely to help others than only the questioner.